# displaying hiddin div with jquery canvas elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have and HTML canvas that has circles drawn onto it.  I am able to get a click event on each circle to display an alert, but I want each one to show a hidden div when clicked. I tried everything I could think of, but it isn't working.  Please help!

HTML:

```
<div id="1" class="toggle" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="2" class="toggle" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="3" class="toggle" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="4" class="toggle" style="display:none"></div>
```

JS: (snippet)

```
    var drawCircle = function (context, x, y, fillcolor, radius, linewidth, strokestyle, fontcolor,    textalign, fonttype, filltext, div, circles) {
    draw(context, x, y, fillcolor, radius, linewidth, strokestyle, fontcolor, textalign, fonttype, filltext);
    var circle = new Circle(x, y, radius);
    circles.push(circle);  
};

drawCircle(context, 300, canvas.height / 2, "green", 40, 5, "#003300", "white", "center", "bold 32px Arial", "1", "#1", circles);
drawCircle(context, 600, canvas.height / 3, "blue", 50, 5, "#003300", "white", "center", "bold 32px Arial", "2", "#2", circles);

$('#mapCanvas').click(function (e) {
    var clickedX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var clickedY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        if (clickedX < circles[i].right && clickedX > circles[i].left && clickedY > circles[i].top && clickedY < circles[i].bottom) {
            /*alert ('clicked number ' + (i + 1));*/
            $(this).attr("div").show;
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $(this).attr("div").show; what is this? Have you set div attribute of any DOM element?

Comment: yes (I think), in the very top line of my js code, there is a list of attributes that are called out for each shape.  I added div, and referenced it in the shape as "#1" and "#2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if 'i' is the number of circle clicked, starting from 0,

this should work.

```
$('#'+(i+1)).show();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm having trouble making it work.

Comment: My apologies, it worked! I was having issues displaying the div.  Thank you, karan